# Atualizar o label de forma automática com Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Gostaria de pegar o valor 1 e subtrair com o valor 2 que o usuário digitar e atualizar o label do resultado de forma automática. Desta forma, conforme o usuário for digitando o label resultado já vai atualizando. Como poderia fazer isso?

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("200x300")

    valor1_content = DoubleVar()
    resultado_content = DoubleVar()

    valor1_content.set(125.55)

    lb_valor1 = Label(root, text="Valor 1")
    lb_valor1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
    lb_valor1_content = Label(root, text="", textvariable=valor1_content)
    lb_valor1_content.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)

    lb_valor2 = Label(root, text="Insere o valor 2")
    lb_valor2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
    valor2_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=resultado_content) 
    valor2_entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4)

    lb_resultado = Label(root, text="Resultado")
    lb_resultado.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
    resultado_entry = Label(root, text="", textvariable=resultado_content) 
    resultado_entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos chamar uma função em cada tecla pressionada para efetuar o cálculo.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")

valor1_content = DoubleVar()
resultado_content = DoubleVar()
resultado = DoubleVar()

def subtrair(e):
    resultado.set(valor1_content.get() - resultado_content.get())

valor1_content.set(125.55)

lb_valor1 = Label(root, text="Valor 1")
lb_valor1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
lb_valor1_content = Label(root, text="", textvariable=valor1_content)
lb_valor1_content.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2)

lb_valor2 = Label(root, text="Insere o valor 2")
lb_valor2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
valor2_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=resultado_content) 
valor2_entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.4)
valor2_entry.bind("<KeyRelease>", subtrair)

lb_resultado = Label(root, text="Resultado")
lb_resultado.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
resultado_entry = Label(root, text="", textvariable=resultado) 
resultado_entry.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6)

root.mainloop()
```